# How to bind UserControl.IsEnabled to its Command

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UserControl declaring a command:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyUserControl));

public ICommand Command
{
    get { return (ICommand) GetValue(CommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
}
```

The command is assigned by parent UI.
How do I bind the UserControl's IsEnabled to the command's availability?

Comment: Sorry, didn't read properly...

Comment: How is your ICommand implemented? Can you change or edit the implementation of the Command? If so, adding a property IsEnabled to the Command would help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(UserControl1),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand), OnCommandChanged));

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand) GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnCommandChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject,
                                         DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var userControl = (UserControl1) dependencyObject;
        var command = dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.OldValue as ICommand;
        if (command != null)
            command.CanExecuteChanged -= userControl.CommandOnCanExecuteChanged;
        command = dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue as ICommand;
        if (command != null)
            command.CanExecuteChanged += userControl.CommandOnCanExecuteChanged;
    }

    private void CommandOnCanExecuteChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        IsEnabled = ((ICommand) sender).CanExecute(null);
    }
```

Comment: I tried my example and everything works fine. What type of ICommand you are using?

Comment: I tried again, yes, it works! Though gives me `sender` as `null` here `IsEnabled = ((ICommand) sender).CanExecute(null);`, so I replaced `sender` directly with `Command`. Weird, seems to be the same solution as @Viv's one, except unsubscription of the event handler.

Comment: The Viv's code is similar, it's strange maybe you missed something when you tried the Viv's solution.

Comment: Might have to do with the type of command being used, but `CommandOnCanExecuteChanged` consistently receives a `null` sender.  Replacing with the `Command` member directly remedies this.  And don't forget to include the `CommandParameter` in your call to `CanExecute` if you've defined one.  I ended up with this:  `IsEnabled = Command.CanExecute(CommandParameter);`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnCurrentCommandChanged));

private static void OnCurrentCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
  UserControl1 currentUserControl = d as UserControl1;
  ICommand newCommand = e.NewValue as ICommand;
  if (currentUserControl == null || newCommand == null)
    return;
  newCommand.CanExecuteChanged += (o, args) => currentUserControl.IsEnabled = newCommand.CanExecute(null);
}

public ICommand Command {
  get {
    return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
  }
  set {
    SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Not sure how the rest of your code is structured. https://www.dropbox.com/s/91z8t0g8lg33mew/MvvmLight1.rar a link to the sample i put together. You can try it with that and compare against the code you have